# Why sqlite3_prepare_v2 close the database?

Tags: ios, database, sqlite

In this database there is a table called "Menu". I want to print this table in my ViewController but this method do not work and close the database immediately.

In DatabaseMenu.h:

```
@interface DatabaseMenu : NSObject {
    sqlite3 *databaseMenu;
    DataBaseMenu *rowMenu;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) int ID; 
@property (nonatomic, copy)NSString *descrizione;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL haSubMenu;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int IDPadre;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *tabelleFigli;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int ordine;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *custView;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL visMappa;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *menuArray;

-(NSMutableArray*) loadDataFromMenu;
+(DatabaseMenu*) database;

@end
```

In DatabaseMenu.m

```
static DatabaseMenu * database;

+(DatabaseMenu*) database{
    if (database==nil) {
        database =[[DatabaseMenu alloc]init];
    }
    return database;
}


-(NSMutableArray*) loadDataFromMenu{ 

    NSString *query = @"SELECT * FROM Menu";

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(databaseMenu, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)
        == SQLITE_OK) {

        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

            //.......

        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);

    } else {        
        sqlite3_close(databaseMenu);
    }

    return self.menuArray;  
}

  -(id) init{ //open database
        self =[super init];
        if(self){
        NSString *sqliteDb = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"China" ofType:@"sqlite"];

         if(sqlite3_open([sqliteDb UTF8String], &databaseMenu)!=SQLITE_OK){

                     NSLog(@"Failed to open database");

            }else {

                     NSLog(@"open the database");



                  [self loadDatiFromMenu];
    }

    return self;
}
```

}

The debugger not get to enter in the while loop. Why?

Comment: What is being returned by the `sqlite3...` statements?  (Here's a page about sqlite error detection: http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html)

Comment: I do not get errors, tells me that the content is 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have done is not proper way to read data from database.

After init the sqlite3 variable have to open the database first and then have to access the database like below

```
if(!sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK)
{
     NSLog(@"An error has occured");
}

const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM Menu";
sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;
if(sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
{
     NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement.");
}

while(sqlite3_step(sqlStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
{
    //get all data from 
}
```

Here `dbPath` is ivar used to store whole path pointing to the data base

Comment: I get "Problem with prepare statement". What can I do?

Comment: does your db contains the table named Menu?

Comment: or may be Menu is one of the reserved word for sqlite just change it to Menus and try again

Comment: My db contains a table named Menu

Answer (score 0):

You define an instance variable `database` in your header file, but also a static variable `database` (that is not a sqlite3 object) in your implementation file.

Are you sure you're using the correct object in `loadDataFromMenu`?

Comment: I changed the name of variable sqlite3 but it still happen the same error, that is after opening the database, it is closed without reading data. What can I do?

Comment: Try adding the code where you initialize the `database` instance variable you're using in `loadDataFromMenu`. My guess is that you're using an uninitialized instance.